# What is the correct audio volume slider formula?

Tags: audio

I'm building a VoIP application. If I take the slider value and just multiply audio samples by it, I get incorrect, nonlinear sounding results. What's the correct formula to get smooth results?

Answer (score 0):

The correct formula is [the decibel formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel#Acoustics) solved for *Prms*. Here's example code in C:

```
// level is 0 to 1, silence is dBFS at level 0
void AdjustVolume(int16_t* buffer, size_t length, float level, float silence = -96)
{
    float factor = pow(10.0f, (1 - level) * silence / 20.0f);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        buffer[i] = static_cast<int16_t>(buffer[i] * factor);
}
```

There's one tweakable: silence. It's the amount of noise when there's no sound. Or: the loudness level below which you can't hear the sound because of the background noise. The theoretical maximum silence for 16 bit audio samples is -96 dB (a sample with integer value of 1 out of 32767). In the real world however, there's background noise produced by the audio equipment and the surroundings of the listener, so you might want to pick a noisier silence level, like -30 dB or something. Picking the correct silence value will maximize the useful surface area of your volume slider, or minimize the amount of slider area where no perceptible change in volume occurs.